# Set values of a jQuery collection using array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

OK this would return an array of node values

```
var vals =  $('.items').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

What's the other way around, what's the setter from an array without the usual iteration including `each`?

Having an array and set each value to the corresponding node from the collection `$('.items')` using the api.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `each`?

Comment: I have no problem with `each`. I'm just interested in jQuery provided another way for an array setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would use [the form of val() that takes a function](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function):

```
$(".items").val(function(index, currentValue) {
    return vals[index];
});
```

The code above will iterate over the elements matching `.items`, and set their values to the respective array elements.

Comment: @Paul, yes, that's what my answer does. I'll clarify.